# Ambiguous use of '!=' operator

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, core-graphics, ambiguous

So, I'm trying to gat `CGPoint`, `CGVector`, and `CGSize` to work nicely for me when using SpriteKit. All of them are just structs with a vertical and horizontal component (vectors). So I made a protocol: `VectorType`

```
protocol VectorType {
    init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)

    var x: CGFloat { get set }
    var y: CGFloat { get set }
}
```

Of course I extended the 3 structs to conform to the protocol and connect the `x`and `y` to the horizontal and vertical components of each struct i.e. `x` returns `dx` for `CGVector` (same for setting), `x` returns `width` for `CGSize` , and nothing for `CGPoint` as they conform to it out of the box, just left the extension empty.

Now I overloaded the "main" operators (`+ - * /`...) so I can effortlessly perform operations involving different types of structs without having to cast them or create new objects, but the main thing here is that I also overloaded the equivalence operators like this:

```
//Compiler requires me to use generics for some reason
func == <T: VectorType, U: VectorType> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y == rhs.y)
}

func != <T: VectorType, U: VectorType> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool {
    return !(lhs == rhs)
}
```

Now, when I test this code everything is fine except for the `!=` operator. For testing these operators I compare sizes to sizes, sizes to vectors, and sizes to points and so on for each type. When I use `==` there is no problem.

[Equal operator test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIm7f.png)

but then, when I use `!=` there is a problem. There is an `Ambiguous use of operator '!='`like this:

[Not equal operator test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ6re.png)

I totally get where this is coming from: overloads for the `==` and `!=` operators comparing `CGVector to CGVector`, `CGPoint to CGPoint`, and `CGSize to CGSize` already exist. They are declared like this

```
@warn_unused_result func ==(lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize) -> Bool
```

There is an overload for every type of course. So I get where the ambiguity comes from, it doesn't know which operator to use when comparing types that are the same. But I don't understand why there is no such problem with the `==` operator in `testEqual()` if we basically have the same situation.

It seems like a compiler bug to me, but I'm not sure, I tried cleaning the project, restarting Xcode, and creating a new project, but to still does not work. Additionally when I try to see the other declaration that causes the ambiguity selecting `Found this candidate` it just shows nothing.

So, the question is: How can I make it work, or can you suggest another way to make it work (that doesn't involve creating a different operator)?

**Update**

I found out that actually the `==` and `!=` implementations being used are actually declared differently. This is how the `==` overload being used is declared

```
@warn_unused_result func ==(lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize) -> Bool
```

AFAIK this should also conflict with my declaration, but it apparently does not.

And here is the other `!=` overload declaration.

```
@warn_unused_result func !=<T : Equatable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool
```

Since `lhs` and `rhs` have the same type and all three types conforming to the VectorType protocol conform to `Equatable` this overload is a candidate for that operation.

I guess the `==` gets used because it explicitly asks for a `CGVector`, `CGPoint` or `CGSize`, and perhaps that takes a precedence over generics. Not sure let me know if you know why both `==` operators do not conflict.

Comment: What happens if you jsut don't override the `!=` definition? It have a default implementation based off `not ==`

Comment: BTW don't use the `CG` prefix for your own types. It's conventionally reserved for CoreGraphics

Comment: Well, I guess I could do that, but it doesn't feel right, I will need to compare manually which is what I'm trying to avoid, but if can't find another solution that is the way I'll go. And yes I was thinking about the CG thing, I'll change it, it was just the first thing that came to my mind when I named it.

Comment: "I will need to compare manually" hmm?

Comment: Now I understand, you meant like using `!(aVector == anotherVector)`, it wouldn't be that bad I guess

Comment: No, I mean that there is a definition (in the standard library) of `!=` as being `!($0 == $1)`. https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Equatable_Protocol/index.html

Comment: You can delete your own definitions of `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

If your type conforms to `Equatable` you are required to define the equality operator `==` for it, but then the standard library provides the inequality operator `!=` for you in terms of your equality operator.

(In fact, if you look at the `Equatable` [protocol requirements](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable) the only required function is `func ==`)

Your ambiguity error is because there are two definitions: your own and the one provided by the compiler.  They both have the same signature, so the compiler can't resolve it.

Just don't define `func !=` yourself - use the provided one.

If you find that you NEED to define it, you're probably not really working with an `Equatable` type.

**Update**

You're not working with equatable types. Asking if a point is equal to a size is meaningless.  Your issues stem from trying to force that to have meaning.

You are providing an Equality operator for every combination of types.  So, you are providing `CGPoint()==CGVector()`, `CGPoint()!=CGVector()`, `CGPoint()=CGSize()`  and `CGPoint()!=CGSize()`, but you're also providing `CGPoint()==CGPoint()` and `CGPoint()!=CGPoint()`, which clash with the ones in CoreGraphics.  read on to understand why you get the error messages that you do, and why `==` seems to work.

**Equality:**

CGPoint, CGVector and CGSize all conform to `Equatable`, and provide an equality operator where both sides are the same type.

You have then provided an equality operator that works on these types via your extension:

```
func == <T: VectorType, U: VectorType> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool
```

This declares an equality operator that works on two `VectorType` objects, even if they're of different underlying types.

The compiler searches for a direct match first, then if it doesn't find it it tries to generate one by substituting types in a generic one.

So, when you say `CGPoint()==CGPoint()` it will look for `func ==(lhs:CGPoint, rhs:CGPoint)->Bool` which it finds in CoreGraphics.

When you say `CGPoint()==CGVector()` it will look for `func ==(lhs:CGPoint, rhs:CGVector)->Bool`. This isn't defined in CoreGraphics or anywhere else, so it moves on to building one from a generic definition.

You have provided:

```
func == <T: VectorType, U: VectorType> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool
```

via your protocol and extensions, so it takes your definition, substitutes `T` with `CGPoint` and `U` with `CGVector` to produce:

```
func == (lhs:CGPoint, rhs:CGPoint) -> Bool
```

It's found one (and only one) useable definition, so it uses it.

**Inequality:**

When you say `CGPoint()!=CGPoint()` it will look for `func !=(lhs:CGPoint, rhs:CGPoint)->Bool` which isn't defined.  It moves to to build one from the generic definitions.  It finds

```
func !=(lhs:T, rhs:T)->Bool
```

in the standard library, substitutes `T` with `CGPoint` to produce:
        func !=(lhs:CGPoint, rhs:CGPoint)->Bool

which satisfies the requirements.

However, since you've declared:

```
func != <T: VectorType, U: VectorType> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool
```

(either directly, or via `Equatable`)

it can substitute both `T` and `U` with CGPoint to get:

```
func !=(lhs:CGPoint, rhs:CGPoint)->Bool
```

Now it has two ways to satisfy the requirements. There is no way to decide which definition it should use, so it stops with the ambiguity error.

Comment: Yeah I did not know the != operator was not required. Anyways I tried not defining it and still did not work, apparently it is  ambiguous because both overloads (the one in core graphics and the one that it gets from equatable) could both be used and the compiler gets confused, not the case with the == operator for some reason, anyways please read the update to see if you know why that is.Though I solved it casting them all to vector_float2 and using that type's operators